# How to change drawable resource at run time?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to change the drawable resource file at runtime.

**.java file code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    str_name = edt1.getText().toString() ;
    str_password = edt2.getText().toString();

    if (str_name == 0 && str_password == 0) {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
    }
    else {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on_button_click);
    }
```

The thing is that it applies the `if` condition but when I enter some text in the `EditText` the resource file does not change.

`EditText`(s) are under `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: You can't compare string using == use .equals() method

Comment: And you can't even compare an object with an integer, as you are currently trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `TextUtils.equals` to judge whether `str_name` equals `0` or not .
- Use `TextUtils.equals` to judge whether `str_password` equals `0` or not .

Try this .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    str_name = edt1.getText().toString();
    str_password = edt2.getText().toString();

    // edited here
    if (TextUtils.equals(str_name, "0") && TextUtils.equals(str_password, "0")) {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
    } else {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on_button_click);
    }
}
```

**Another way to solve it .**

```
if (Double.parseDouble(str_name) == 0 && Double.parseDouble(str_password) == 0) {
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
} else {
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on_button_click);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your conditional statement with below code

```
if (str_name.equalsIgnoreCase("0") && str_password.equalsIgnoreCase("0") {

    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);

}
```

You cannot use == for comparing 2 strings. Hope that helps you.

Comment: but didn't change the button values when i entered the text in edit texts

Comment: Use this answer with EditText's addTextChangeListener method for both of your edittexts and place abdul's waheed code in afterTextChanged method.